# In a convex Quadrilateral ABCD, $\measuredangle ABC = \measuredangle BCD = 120^{\circ}$.Prove that: $ AC + BD \ge AB + BC + CD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In a convex Quadrilateral ABCD, $\measuredangle ABC  = \measuredangle BCD = 120^{\circ}$.Prove that:

$$ AC + BD \ge AB + BC + CD$$

My attempt

Tried to use cosine formula twice' i.e ($\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BCD$) and tried to make and inequality.But couldn't prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the question is :
$AC+BD > AB+BC+CD$

$AC=\sqrt{AB^2+BC^2+AB*BC}=\sqrt{(AB+\dfrac{BC}{2})^2+\dfrac{3BC^2}{4}}>AB+\dfrac{BC}{2} $

$BD=\sqrt{CD^2+BC^2+CD*BC}=\sqrt{(CD+\dfrac{BC}{2})^2+\dfrac{3BC^2}{4}}>CD+\dfrac{BC}{2} $

$AC+BD>AB+BC+CD$

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QHQS.jpg)Like the image, we can extend AB and DC.
And let two lines meet at point E.
Then, angle BCE and BEC is 60° .(because it is 180°-120°)
Then we can draw perpendicular line for ED that crosses B, and let the meeting point of AE and this line G. In the same way, we can draw perpendicular line for BE that crosses C, and let the meeting point of CE and this line H. Then
BH=1/2 BC and CG=1/2 BC.
And we can see △AHC and △DBG are right triangles. So, DB>DG, AC>AH, because in rignt triangle, hypotenuse is longer than other sides. And if we add these two inequalities, we get DB+AC>AH+DG=AB+BH+CG+DC=AB+BC+DC.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).